# What can I do with these white items?

Tags: the-secret-world

I have a bunch of talismans and a few weapons that can't be disassembled because they are white. What else can I do with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that almost all QL-1 items that you get at the start of the game have no value.. You can 'sell' them to get rid of them for no profit but you can not, as you have state, disassemble them.

As far as I can tell this is to stop you from looping around and just picking up the items over and over again and getting materials or cash for these items.